# Average value of list

Tags: c#, list, stopwatch

I want to make code that will on the first click start `rotorSpeed` stopwatch then on the second click add `rotorSpeed.ElapsedMilliseconds` to `list`. On the second click resets stopwatch and starts timing again, then on the third click again adds `rotorSpeed.ElapsedMilliseconds` to `list`.
There are no errors in the code, but when I debug it, I get an error on `double average = list.Average();`

`Stopwatch rotorSpeed = new Stopwatch();
 List<double> list = new List<double>();`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    //Getting rotor speed
    if (i != 2)
    {               
        if (rotorSpeed.IsRunning)
        {
            rotorSpeed.Stop();
            list.Add(rotorSpeed.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            rotorSpeed.Start();                   
        }
        else
        {
            rotorSpeed.Reset();
            rotorSpeed.Start();
        }
    }

    double average = list.Average();
    textBox2.Text = average.ToString();
}
```

This is the error I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in >System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: What the error you got?

Comment: That's probably because you're trying to get an `Average` of list with no elements after the first click. What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: @pavnik An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: wrap last two lines with if (list.Count > 1)

Answer (score 23):

Your `list` is empty and so calling `Average()` on it throwing exception. Change the below line

```
double average = list.Average();
```

to

```
double average = list.Count > 0 ? list.Average() : 0.0;
```

Comment: Why `0.0`? Is it your opinion that one can silently use zero? Another option would be `list.Count > 0 ? list.Average() : double.NaN`. The average of an empty sequence can be said to be `0.0 / 0.0`, in a sense.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (list.Count > 0)
{
    textBox2.Text = list.Average().ToString();
}
```

Comment: count should be greater than equal to 1.

Comment: Why? It doesn't make any sense to make an average of 1 element. LE: Unless that's what it is required to be shown in the textbox. In which case I guess you would be right :)

Comment: Textbox will not be populated if your list count is 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (list.Count > 1)
{
    double average = list.Average();
    textBox2.Text = average.ToString();
    rotorSpeed.Stop();
}
```

This works just fine. Thanks!